# React native apk versionName problemi i want to change versionName 1.0.1

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-play, react-native-maps

I have a react native app, and I installed google play, and i wanna update this project in google play but i dont know how to get current aab file, How can I do as versionName 1.0.1 in output.json file?[image: output.json image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `version` in your `app.json` file of your project.